# How to say "addiction"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Addiction, addict and addicted... what are these words in Esperanto?

I found *dependi* and *manio*, but I believe those concepts are completely different. A baby can be dependent on its mother, and an old man on his medicine, but an addiction is a different thing. *Mania* immidiately makes me think of bipolar disease, but I know it is used in English also more generally, for an extreme or excessive enthusiasm. It carries a nuance of insanity.

When I looked through PIV there was no sign below either of the roots that they are used when talking about things like drugs, alcohol and gambling. The defintitions didn't change my former impression of which concepts they represent.

What do you say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I looked through PIV there was no sign below either of the roots that they are used when talking about things like drugs, alcohol and gambling

I can see very clear signs of just that. Take a look at http://vortaro.net/#manio:

> **toksomanio** Vd [tokso](http://vortaro.net/#tokso).

If you follow the link, you will see:

> **toksiĝemulo**. toksomaniulo.
>
> **toksomanio**. Kutima k ekscesa uzado, per ingesto aŭ injekto, de toksoj, pli speciale de drogoj, ekz. alkoholo, kokaino, morfino, nikotino, opiaj alkaloidoj: *toksomanio estas ofte noca k estigas alkutimiĝon k psikan k/aŭ korpan dependecon.*
>
> **toksomaniulo**. Malsanulo trafita de toksomanio.

*Toksomanio* looks like the word for “drug addiction”, and “an addict” would be *toksiĝemulo* or *toksomaniulo*. I haven't found the word for “addicted”, but we can analyse the word *toksiĝ-em-ul-o* as “a person with an inclination to ingest toxic substances”, so *toksiĝema* should mean “with an inclination to ingest toxic substances”, that is, “addicted”.

Note that Google doesn't give any results for *toksiĝema*, so there may be some other possibilities. And all these *tokso-* words are about the addiction to drugs and other substances. If you want to talk about addiction to gambling, Internet, porn, etc. you'll need to combine other words with *-em-*, *manio* and/or *dependeco*.

Comment: Ah, I didn't follow the link to the page based on the root *tokso*. My bad, thank you.  Do you have any suggestions for addict and addicted? If so, could you add that to make this answer complete?

Comment: @AntoniaMontaro I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

On the other hand, there's nothing in vortaro.net to suggest that it can't be applied to drug addiction.

- ***manio*** Fortega nenormala konstanta inklino al io

I note that this is also the word listed in Benson (CEED) for addiction.